# Right Engel Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $$R_{2}(G)=\{g\in G\mid [g,x,x]=1,~~ \forall x\in G \}$$

*Kappe* in "W P Kappe, Die A-Norm einer Gruppe, Illinois J. Math. 5 (1961)"

proved that $R_{2}(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$. Now if we define $R_{2}(x)=\{g\in G\mid [g,x,x]=1\}$, then do this subset is  a subgroup of $G$?

Here $[g,x,x]=[[g,x],x]$.

Thank you

Comment: Maryam, behtar bud yek linke monaseb baraye `Kappe` miyovordid.

Comment: Sorry, what is $[g,x,x]$? Is this $[[g,x],x]$?

Comment: Try $(1,2) \in S_5$

Comment: That was my suggestion, yes. An element of $S_5$ lies in $R_2((1,2))$ if and only if it maps $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{4,5\}$ or $\{3,5\}$.

Comment: Yes that's right, it has order 48.

Comment: @ Derek Holt. Thank you very much Prof. Holt.

Comment: @ Derek Holt. Do there exist a condition ( or conditions) on group $G$ such that $R_{2}(x)$ to be a subgroup of $G$ for all $x\in G$.?

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint in the comments by Derek Holt.

In general the set defined by the original poster, $R(x)$, need not be a group. 
For example consider $x=(1,2)$ and $G=S_{5}$, then for $g \in S_5$:

we see that $[g,x,x]=1 \iff  g$ maps $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ or $\{3,4\}$ or $\{3,5\}$ or $\{4,5\}$.

<sub><sup>(To see this you could expand the commutator and end up with something like $((1,2)(1,2)^{g})^2=1$).</sup></sub>

Then $R_{2}((1,2))$ is not a group since it contains $(1,3)(2,4)$ and $(1,4)(2,5)$  but not their product.